# how to use NCover (free) in maven builds

Tags: .net, maven, ncover

Just an inquiry on how to integrated NCover (free) in .Net project (maven build)

I looked at hudson but I guess I can't use it in maven.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

we're looking at implementing this in NPanday very shortly: http://npanday.codeplex.com/workitem/12946